# how to find the weblogic server start time in unix box

Tags: unix-shell

how to find the weblogic server start time in unix.
i have give ps -f | grep port number

but it is showing my current system time.

how to find this

Answer (score 1):

I use this in in Linux and Solaris to find a process in ps based listening ports.

```
ps -ef | grep `lsof  -i :7001 | grep "LISTEN"|awk '{print $2}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add e(Select all processes) argument:

```
ps -ef | grep PORT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the time resolution you need. If the process started more than 24 hours ago you'll have only the date of its start given in ps -ef output.

Try looking into the system's logs. There's a good chance that the starting server wrote a line or two into the log.